# How to activate a new module in magento 1 this module should create a table

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, setup-script, installer, codepools

I am trying to activate a new module in Magento 1. Here are my actions step-by-step:

1. I created a new file in `/app/etc/modules`, called : `Mage_ContactMessage.xml` :
   [image]
2. I created a new folder in `/app/code/core/Mage`, called `ContactMessage` : 
   with 2 folders : `/etc` & `/sql`
3. The file `config.xml` in `/etc` : 
   [image]
4. The file `install-1.6.0.0.php` from `/sql/contactmessage_setup` : 
   [image]

The table is not being created, and I don't understand why. Please help me

Comment: Can you add your table name instead of contactmessage/stock?

Comment: I tried like this : `$installer->getTable('contactmessage_stock')` and the same problem

Comment: Remove the entry from core_resource table for your module then try.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, which `entry` ?

Comment: Can you goto the table core_resource? Open that table, you will find a row contactmessage_setup with version. Delete that entry and try again.

Comment: strange but this data not exist in `core_resource` : `SELECT * FROM `core_resource` WHERE code = 'contactmessage_setup' ` 0 results

Comment: Did you check manually if its exist or not?

Comment: Yes..............

Comment: I confirm that not exist

Comment: Please edit this question to include the actual code, instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Upload the module to

> app/code/local/Mage/ContactMessage

instead of

> app/code/core/Mage/ContactMessage

Because you have mentioned the codepool to local.

Or you can modify the codepool to core. But this is not a best practice.

Comment: I can't do that, because the project exist, maybe modify `codepool` to `core` ?

Comment: Yes either you can try to modify it to core.

Comment: And normally the creation of table should be done on refresh of doesn't matter which page from project right ?

Comment: Yes whenever you refresh the page installer will run but make sure cache is not enabled otherwise you need to refresh the cache as well.

Comment: The same problem...

Comment: Is this module is working?

Comment: I'm newbie in magento and don't know how I can test that

Comment: Where did you find that module? Did you develop your own? Because custom module always use codepool local or community. If you develop this module then try to rename the names like Mage to any custom name and use the codepool local or community.

Comment: Yes I developed like others modules in this project

Comment: Can you post your whole module in your question not image screenshot. Paste the codes so that I can modify and update the answer with working code.

Comment: The idea is that I can't put code stackoverflow drop an error. But all my code from this module is in images that I put in the question

Comment: The idea of this module is only to create a table in database

Comment: Please try this blog to work with new module: https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-module-creating-installer-script/